# Smoothness of a vector valued function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function which maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What does it mean for $f$ to be $C^1$, i.e. continuously differentiable?

Am I correct to think that each "component" of $f = (f_1,f_2,\dots,f_3)$ needs to be $C^1$, so that the entries of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ are all continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. However, the term smooth is for functions that are $C^\infty$,i.e, infinitely differentiable.

Comment: "smooth" is whatever the author says it is; there's no one definition of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary for each component to have an everywhere continuous derivative. But existence of dervatives with respect to $x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ is not enough for differentiability of $f$. One may have, for example
$$
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)(0,0)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)(0,0)=0
$$
but the direction derivative in the direction of $(1,1)$ is not $0$, so no tangent plane exists.  In that case $f$ is not differentiable at that point despite the existence of partial derivatives.