# Defining smoothness of a single-valued real function of a vector without appealing to partial derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

My question is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840403) which asks about proving that the squared norm $\vec{v} \mapsto \| \vec{v} \|^2$ is smooth.

The most straightforward way to define smoothness for a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is to use partial derivatives, as is done in the body of the question itself as well as [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411943/smoothness-of-a-vector-valued-function). Those definitions boil down to:

- a function $f$ is smooth if and only if all of its partial derivatives of any order exist and are continuous.

The context of the original question was to avoid using *partial derivatives* until they've been mentioned in the text, but my motivation for asking this question is slightly different. **I'm wondering whether it can be done at all, *even using machinery that is way more powerful than that referenced in the original question*.**

Definitions that are completely geometric or impractical for computing derivatives (or don't talk about derivatives at all) are all totally fine.

All I can really see as a means of avoiding talking about partial derivatives is just to substitute [directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), since those are still functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient), unfortunately, would be a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so it's not clear how to iterate it.

Comment: Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open. Call a mapping $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth if it maps smooth curves in $U$ to smooth curves. This conincides with the usual smooth mappings. See Boman, Jan. "Differentiability of a Function and of its Compositions with Functions of One Variable.".

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Higher_derivatives) and [the other answer by freakish in the first linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840403/prove-that-fx-x-2-is-smooth-using-the-definition-of-total-derivative/4840481#4840481) (in particular the second half of it).